# Two tables count in to two seprate columns

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count, subquery

i have two tables eg:

```
table1
---------------------
|id | name| isActive|
|---|-----|---------|
| 1 | dd  |    1    |
| 1 | cc  |    1    |
| 1 | zz  |    1    |
| 1 | yy  |    1    |
---------------------


table2
---------------------
|id | name| isActive|
|---|----|----------|
| 1 | ab  |    1    |
| 1 | cd  |    1    |
| 1 | ef  |    1    |
| 1 | gh  |    1    |
---------------------
```

the requirements are to get count of both tables and print them in to two separate columns and print it into two separate columns in birt Report i have tried this

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(table2.`name`) Table1Count,
  table1.`isActive` Table1IsActive ,
  COUNT(table2.`name`) Table2Count,
  table2.`isActive` Table2IsActive 
FROM
  `table1`,
  `table2`
```

its out put is in two separate columns but with cross join

```
Table1Count  isActive  Table2Count  Table2IsActive  
-----------  --------  -----------  ----------------
  43316         0         3536                 1
```

i can not use any join because there is no relationship in both of these table while its output is similar to the desired out put where i want two tables counts in separate columns

by trying this i get two separate rows

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM
   (SELECT 
   COUNT(*) Table1Count,
    table1.`isActive` Table1IsActive 
  FROM
    `table1` 
  UNION
  SELECT 
    COUNT(*) Table2Count,
    table2.`isActive` Table2IsActive 
  FROM
    `table2 `) AS a
```

its output is in two separate rows while my requirements are separate columns

```
Table1Count   Table1IsActive 
------------   --------------
    442           0
     98           1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your UNION, add extra columns for the columns from the other table. Then combine them using `MAX()`

```
SELECT MAX(Table1Count) AS Table1Count, MAX(Table1IsActive) AS Table1IsActive,
       MAX(Table2Count) AS Table2Count, MAX(Table2IsActive) AS Table2IsActive
FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) Table1Count, table1.`isActive` Table1IsActive, 0 Table2Count, 0 Table2IsActive
      FROM `table1` 
      UNION
      SELECT 0 Table1Count, 0 Table1IsActive, COUNT(*) Table2Count, table2.`isActive` Table2IsActive 
      FROM `table2`) AS a
```

Comment: Unknown column 'Table2Count' in 'field list' :(

Comment: Did you forget the `0` before `Table2Count` on line 3?

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '0 Table1Count,

Comment: BTW, this will return a random `isActive` row from each table. Did you want something more specific, like `MAX(isActive)`?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table1`) AS Table1Count, 
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table2`) AS Table2Count;
```

Comment: its working fine for count only but i needed other columns as well, by the way i got the answer and thanks for sharing this approach

Answer (score 1):

`UNION` will always use the column names from the first select in the union. Since both queries return a single row, what you can use is a simple cartesian product (1 x 1 = 1) to combine the queries:

```
SELECT t1.Table1Count, t1.Table1IsActive, t2.Table2Count, t2.Table2IsActive
FROM
   (SELECT 
   COUNT(*) Table1Count,
   table1.isActive Table1IsActive 
  FROM
    table1
  GROUP BY table1.isActive
    ) as t1,
  (SELECT 
    COUNT(*) Table2Count,
    table2.isActive Table2IsActive 
  FROM
    table2 
  GROUP BY table2.isActive      
  ) as t2;
```

**Edit**

Update from comments - I believe what you are after is as follows, viz to count all rows AND also count just the active rows (in one single query) and then repeat this across two tables, to project a single row result:

```
SELECT 
       t1.Table1Count, t1.Table1Active, t2.Table1Count, t2.Table2Active
FROM
    (
       SELECT COUNT(t1.id) AS Table1Count, 
              SUM(CASE WHEN t1.IsActive = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Table1Active 
       FROM Table1 t1
    ) t1,
    (
       SELECT COUNT(t2.id) AS Table1Count, 
              SUM(CASE WHEN t2.IsActive = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Table2Active 
       FROM Table2 t2
    ) t2;
```

It is important that both of the derived tables (t1 and t2) each flatten to a single row, otherwise the cartesian product will duplicate rows.

Comment: I'm thinking that your sample data isn't representative, e.g. that you have both isActive = 0 and IsActive = 1 rows of data ?

Comment: yes @stuartLC i do have both isActive=0 or isActive=1

Comment: @Programmer then I guess you actually want 6 columns in the result, i.e. `Table1Count, T1Active, T1InActive, Table2Count, T2Active, T2Inactive` in order to be able to represent both permutations of active in both tables?

Comment: no i want 4 columns table1IsActive, table2IsActive, table1Count, table2Coun actually this is just a sample query i need more than 4 columns in actual query

Comment: i will rewrite that actual query if i will have this query working fine

Comment: @Programmer - I've taken a final guess that you want a total of all rows per table, and a count of active rows per table, for two tables, reported as a single row.